# Get the next semi-week end date

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have the following code, which simulates a week start on Saturday and then divides the week in 2 parts, returning Tuesday if the given date is Sat-Tue, else it returns Fri. I would like to know if this can be done with fewer math operations?

```
private static DateTime SemiWeeklyEndDate(DateTime date)
{
    if (((7 + (date.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Saturday)) % 7) <= ((7 + (DayOfWeek.Tuesday - DayOfWeek.Saturday)) % 7))
        return date.AddDays((((int)DayOfWeek.Tuesday - (int)date.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7));

    return date.AddDays((((int)DayOfWeek.Friday - (int)date.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7));
}
```

Comment: If you have working code, this might be a better fit for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I'm a newbie here, and I would like to get some feedback, on why this question was closed.

Comment: I think the issue is that "Can this be simplified?" as a question is subjective (just look at the varying responses). If you can turn it into an objective question like, "Can this be done with fewer modulo operations" you'd be good. Otherwise, if it's "Hey, review this for me please, comments welcome", then you should post this in [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify the whole thing by computing the proper offset for every day of the week from the built-in DOW values:

```
| DOW       | Value | Offset | TUE | FRI |
| Saturday  | 6     |  3     |  3  |  6  |
| Sunday    | 0     |  2     |  2  |  5  |
| Monday    | 1     |  1     |  1  |  4  |
| Tuesday   | 2     |  0     |  0  |  3  |
| Wednesday | 3     |  2     |  6  |  2  |
| Thursday  | 4     |  1     |  5  |  1  |
| Friday    | 5     |  0     |  4  |  0  |
```

This turns out to be a simple double modulo formula:

```
private static DateTime SemiWeeklyEndDate(DateTime date) => date.AddDays((9 - (int)date.DayOfWeek) % 7 % 4);
```

Derivation of the formula:

For going up to Tuesday, you have

```
((DayOfWeek.Tuesday - date.DayOfWeek) + 7) % 7
((2 - date.DayOfWeek) + 7) % 7
(9 - date.DayOfWeek) % 7
```

which gives the TUE column above.

For going up to Friday, you have

```
((DayOfWeek.Friday - date.DayOfWeek) + 7) % 7
((5 - date.DayOfWeek) + 7) % 7
(12 - date.DayOfWeek) % 7
```

which gives the FRI column above. Comparing TUE and FRI to Offset, we see we can apply one more mod to TUE to get the Offset.

Sample output from this method (EndDate) and the original (OrigEndDate):

```
StartDate       EndDate         OrigEndDate
Sat 11/30/19    Tue 12/03/19    Tue 12/03/19
Sun 12/01/19    Tue 12/03/19    Tue 12/03/19
Mon 12/02/19    Tue 12/03/19    Tue 12/03/19
Tue 12/03/19    Tue 12/03/19    Tue 12/03/19
Wed 12/04/19    Fri 12/06/19    Fri 12/06/19
Thu 12/05/19    Fri 12/06/19    Fri 12/06/19
Fri 12/06/19    Fri 12/06/19    Fri 12/06/19
```

Of course, you could just use an array to map `DayOfWeek` to the offset:

```
private static int[] DOWToOffsetMap = new[] { 3, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0 };    
private static DateTime SemiWeeklyEndDate2(DateTime date) => date.AddDays(DOWToOffsetMap[(int)date.DayOfWeek]);
```

Comment: Sorry but that function does not return the correct answer. Am I missing something?

Comment: @User2585 When I use this function versus your function, I get the same results?

Comment: You're right, great answer, not sure why someone down-voted

Comment: @User2585 FYI, I added an array mapped version if you want to trade storage for performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can create something a bit more readable by using local functions:

```
private static DateTime SemiWeeklyEndDate(DateTime date)
{
    int DaysBetween(DayOfWeek from, DayOfWeek to) => (to - from + 7) % 7;
    int DaysToEndOfWeek(DayOfWeek from) => DaysBetween(from, DayOfWeek.Saturday);

    var pastMidWeek = DaysToEndOfWeek(date.DayOfWeek) <= DaysToEndOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Tuesday);

    var daysOffset =
        pastMidWeek
            ? DaysBetween(DayOfWeek.Tuesday, date.DayOfWeek)
            : DaysBetween(DayOfWeek.Friday, date.DayOfWeek);

    return date.AddDays(daysOffset);
}
```

I think this version conveys the behavior you're after without excessive modulo maths.

Comment: Right, that's obvious... I'm wondering if there is something in the logic that can be simplified

Comment: Then @NetMage answer will be perfect for you.

Comment: I've updated to better convey the logic.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I like doing these type of problems

```
            DateTime jan1 = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1);
            DateTime firstSaturday = jan1.AddDays(6 - (int)jan1.DayOfWeek);

            DateTime today = DateTime.Now.Date;
            int daysFromSemiWeekBegin = today.Subtract(firstSaturday).Days % 14;

            DateTime semiWeekEnd = (daysFromSemiWeekBegin == 0) ? today : today.AddDays(14 - daysFromSemiWeekBegin);
```